# Remove trigger from information_schema DB

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

At school, we are learning to write triggers in SQL and I wrote one, but it's wrong. Therefore, I would like to delete it.

I tried the following:

```
mysql> use information_schema
Database changed
mysql> drop trigger log;
ERROR 1360 (HY000): Trigger does not exist
```

But as you see, I get an error because it does not exist.
When I use Sequel Pro and check that table with `select * from triggers;`, it shows me there IS a trigger called log. See screenshot:

[image: Trigger is available]

I tried removing it by right-clicking and click on "delete row", but then I get the following error:

> Couldn't delete rows.
>
> MySQL said: Access denied for user 'robbert'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'

How am I supposed to remove that trigger? It's clearly there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TRIGGER_SCHEMA` column indicates the database in which your trigger is defined: you'll need to `USE db5`, not `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` (or else qualify the trigger name in the `DROP TRIGGER` statement):

```
USE db5;
DROP TRIGGER log;
```

Or:

```
DROP TRIGGER db5.log;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using like this:

**Syntax:**

```
DROP TRIGGER [IF EXISTS] [schema_name.]trigger_name
```

In your case:

```
 DROP TRIGGER [IF EXISTS] db5.log;
```

The error occured because you were using a wrong schema name. The schema name should be `db5` not `information_schema`

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger is in the db5 schema.  You need to either use that schema prior to dropping

```
use db5;
drop trigger log;
```

or use the fully qualified trigger name in the drop statement

```
drop trigger db5.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, when I renamed table, I couldn't drop trigger.

You have to script table, then drop it (it will drop all the triggers from information_schema.triggers), finally recreate the table.